# Confusing SML statement

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have this statement:

```
let val x = 
    let val x = 5
    in(fn y =>(y,x+y))
    end
     in
     let val y=3 and z=10
     in x z 
     end 
     end;
```

The output is :

```
(10,15)
```

I've been trying to track how this answer was produced but am getting confused. Is there a better way to write this that would help me understand what variables are being used where? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, some alpha-conversion:

```
let val fnPairOfInputAndInputPlus5 = 
    let val five = 5
     in ( fn input => ( input, five + input ) )
    end
 in let val ignored = 3 and input = 10
     in fnPairOfInputAndInputPlus5 input 
    end 
end;
```

This code is demonstrating that when you declare a function value, unbound values in the declaring scope, such as the value `five`, are "enclosed" by the declaration (hence the term "closures").  Thus the function always returns a pair consisting of its input and its input plus five.

Comment: Thanks! That clears up a lot. I'm still confused on what 'fnPairofinputAndInputPlus5 input' is. You're calling that value with an argument of input?

Comment: right.  function call notation in ML is just `f x` or `( f x )` for function `f` and argument `x`.  Functions of two arguments can either accept a single *tuple* with both args `f (x,y)`, or they can be *curried* functions `f x y` = `( f x ) y` = `( ( f x ) y )`.  In the latter case `f x` returns another function.

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify it to

```
let fun f y = (y,5+y)
    val y=3 and z=10
in
  f z
end;
```

Note that the two instances of y are independent. The inner occurrence of x (which I've eliminated) is independent of the outer one (now renamed f).

Answer (score 0):

Can be understood using manual evaluation with detailed explanations.

Starting with your initial expression:

```
let val x = 
   let val x = 5
   in (fn y => (y,x + y))
   end
in
   let val y = 3 and z = 10
   in x z 
   end 
end;
```

Line 2,3,4 is an expression whose type is a function, as you see in the `in` part. It does not depends on any outer context, so it may be simplified as just `fn y => (y, 5 + y)`, substituting `x` to `5`, according to the binding given in `let`.

So you now have this:

```
let val x = fn y => (y, 5 + y)
in
   let val y = 3 and z = 10
   in x z 
   end 
end;
```

After substitution of `x` (and removal of the `let` which in then now not necessary any more):

```
let val y = 3 and z = 10
in (fn y => (y, 5 + y)) z 
end;
```

Note the `y` appearing in `(y, 5 + y)` are bound to the function's argument, and not to `3`. There is no reference to this outer `y`, so its biding may be removed.

Now you have:

```
let z = 10
in (fn y => (y, 5 + y)) z 
end;
```

Substituting `z` to `10` and removing the `let` which is not necessary any more, you get:

```
(fn y => (y, 5 + y)) 10;
```

This is a function application. You may evaluate it, to get:

```
(10, 5 + 10);
```

Which gives the final and constant result you noticed:

```
(10, 15);
```